# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

We have been trying to debug a Core Data multiple-context/threading issue wherein merging a Core Data save notification into our main thread `NSManagedObjectContext` is sporadically crashing the app. This is crashing ~2% of our app sessions and we are at a loss as to how to solve this. We would really appreciate any guidance or general advice on what could possibly cause this crash.

We have a Core Data setup that looks like this:

[image: Core Data Stack]
*N.B. This is the default Core Data stack in Magical Record v2.3 created from [MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack]*

This is the scenario where our app is crashing:

1. HTTP request returns JSON
2. JSON is parsed into `NSManagedObject`s (Some new entities, some updated entities) on **Root Saving Context**
3. **Root Saving Context** saves to persistent store
4. `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` is broadcast by Core Data. Default context on main queue observes this and calls `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` with the `NSDictionary` of changes on the main thread.
5. It crashes when `objectID` is sent to an invalid object (most likely `NSManagedObject` has been deallocated).

This is occurring inside the private implementation of `NSManagedObjectContext` `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` so it is impossible for us to see what has actually gone wrong here; all we can tell at this point that an object which should exist, does not.

[image]

This only happens on a small percent of Core Data saves, indicating that may not be a fundamental flaw in our Core Data →  API stack. Moreover, there is no indication that the size or type of the changes (insertions/updates/deletions) in the context changes have any impact on the likelihood of the crash.

Comment: What type of concurrency do these MOCs use? And are you using `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` when merging changes?

Comment: The Default MoC uses main queue concurrency type and Root Saving MoC uses Private Queue concurrency type. Any interation with any private queues in the app use performBlock or performBlockAndWait. As per the Apple Documentation, we don't interact with the Default context through perform block, we do however ensure that we never interact with it when we are not on the main thread.

Comment: Just my 2ct; I had such an issue once while doing everything by the book, and it was caused by an `NSLog()` of the `NSNotification` object (or the `userInfo` property thereof). Since then I only do `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` immediately followed by `save` on the context, not touching the notification in any other way. Since then I've never seen it segfault again.

Comment: Given that the root MOC is on a private queue, is there more to the stack trace from other threads? Is it possible the object it is trying to reference is one that has been deleted (or otherwise removed) in the child MOC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been some time now since this question was posted and after rediscovering it I'd like to answer my own question for the sake of others who find this thread.

In my circumstance I had migrated a large code base from sibling `NSManagedObjectContexts` updated via `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`'s. However the problem was not really anything to do with this, even though this did expose the issue.

The real cause of this were places that there were older parts of the code, setup by previous engineers, that had setup KVO on `NSManagedObject`s and their properties. It transpired that KVO on Core Data entities is in fact a very very bad idea.

More accurately, it appeared that this happened when KVO was setup on entities and either the object, or the target of a relationship on this object was deleted from the `NSPersistentStore`. This second condition seemed to not be the *only* cause of the issue, but was definitely a very prominent cause in my situation.

Lesson's learnt:

1. Use a fetched results controller when you need to. KVO is not a convenient shortcut and you shouldn't avoid migrating dodgy Core Data KVO code to NSFetchedResultsControllers or another sensible alternative as the procrastination will just hurt you.
2. Multi threaded Core Data is a difficult but very worthwhile skill to become an expert in. Knowing your Core Data stack and the nuances and limitations of Core Data multithreading is absolutely worth all the mental anguish.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation of `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` says that:

"You can pass the notification object to `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` on another thread, however you must not use the managed object in the user info dictionary directly on another thread. For more details, see Concurrency with Core Data in Core Data Programming Guide."

Maybe this is the issue? I would make sure the object u get from the notification is getting saved on Default Context on the same thread it was posted by Root.

Comment: This was exactly my issue. I forgot to dispatch by calling `performBlock` on the ManagedObjectContext.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that your persistent store has become corrupted and is in an inconsistent state. If this happens an error code is generated which Magical Record does not necessarily deal with. This can be the source of a number of difficult-to-repeat apparently-random crashes related to Magical Record (and may or may not be considered a Magical Record bug).

It's worth reading the Magical Record issues threads  [here](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/877) (same issue) and [here](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/270) (different issue, but could be similar cause). When I hit these problems I managed to make some temporary patch fixes following various hints in those threads, but ultimately I decided to remove my dependency on Magical Record, and I have had no problems since then.